# Trying to pass data to Action Method using AJAX POST in MVC 5

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to capture a notes/comment from Jquery's Bootbox text area and sending it to an action method which accepts a parameter, but i am not hitting the breakpoint of that action method.

My jquery in the View.cshtml:

```
 $(function () {
                if ($('#stafId').is(':checked')) {
                    bootbox.prompt({
                        title: "Please add Project Note for STAF selection",
                        inputType: 'textarea',
                        callback: function (result) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: 'POST',
                                url: '/Requirement/SaveProjectNotes',
                                data: { notes: result } 
                            });
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

And my action method in the controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveProjectNotes(string notes)
    {
       // TODO :

        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Requirement", new { page = -1 });
    }
```

I am not sure why i am not hitting the action method.  Any pointers would be of great help.

TIA.

Comment: Open the network tab of dev tools and check what the response text and status code is of the request. It should give you some useful information to debug.

Comment: A redirect isn't going to work from an AJAX post.  You have to return Json or Content that you can use to redirect on the client using window.location

Comment: @BrianMains : redirect works fine with my other AJAX calls.